# how to fix .props file error for Stanford NLP built with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to build an eclipse project for stanford coreNLP but getting errors for my customized properties file created as a class with main method.
Could anyone help me solving the following errors with my new "properties (.prop)" code, please?

**Errors returned by eclipse are**:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments     at the line 25; line 27:  Multiple markers at
>     this line
> - The method get(Class)
>     is undefined for the type      CoreMap
> - CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation cannot be resolved to a type
> - SemanticGraph cannot be resolved to a type.

My properties code is:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import   edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation;

public class NLP {
    /**
    * @param <CoreMap>
    * @param args
    */
    public static <CoreMap> void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, depparse");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    String text = "This is a sentence I want to parse.";
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

    pipeline.annotate(document);
    List<CoreMap>sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
        SemanticGraph dependencies =     sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println(dependencies.toDotFormat());
    }
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You probably have the wrong import for List - you have `java.awt.List`, most likely you need `java.util.List`.

Comment: @greg-449: yes, indeed it's one of the errors. thanks for pointing it out. though that didn't yet fix all code, still need to find a solution... thanks, anyway.